# Converted list of multi nested dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Trying to unpack (what I believe to be called) a list of multi-nested dictionaries to achieve the following output:

```
   subject_code               module                                              notes        topics       start         end faculty_id faculty_leader
0            90  ABC Board Spring 19  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1A, 2G, 3S]  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn
1            80  ABC Board Spring 18  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1D, 5F, 2B]  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn
```

Below is the raw data and my unsuccessful attempts to achieve the aforementioned output:

```
import pandas as pd

data_ = [
         {
          "subject_code": 90, "module": "ABC Board Spring 19", 
          "notes" : "refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general-information/overleaf", 
          "topics" : ['1A', '2G', '3S'], "start":1643847382,"end":1644279382, 
          "faculty":{"id":"nothing","leader":"Steve Finn"}
           },
         {
          "subject_code": 80, "module": "ABC Board Spring 18", 
          "notes" : "refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general-information/overleaf", 
          "topics" : ['1D', '5F', '2B'], "start":1643847382,"end":1644279382, 
          "faculty":{"id":"nothing","leader":"Steve Finn"}}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_ )
print(df)
```

However, the final column `faculty` is not displaying as desired....

```
   subject_code               module                                              notes        topics       start         end                                    faculty
0            90  ABC Board Spring 19  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1A, 2G, 3S]  1643847382  1644279382  {'id': 'nothing', 'leader': 'Steve Finn'}
1            80  ABC Board Spring 18  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1D, 5F, 2B]  1643847382  1644279382  {'id': 'nothing', 'leader': 'Steve Finn'}
```

Rather than `faculty` displaying as a single column containing a dictionary of data I would like split into individual columns, named as dictionary name and key...

Below is the desired output as shown at the start of this thread:

```
   subject_code               module                                              notes        topics       start         end faculty_id faculty_leader
0            90  ABC Board Spring 19  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1A, 2G, 3S]  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn
1            80  ABC Board Spring 18  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1D, 5F, 2B]  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). Renaming the columns to the desired names is an exercise I leave for the reader.

```
pd.json_normalize(data_)

   subject_code               module                                              notes        topics       start         end faculty.id faculty.leader
0            90  ABC Board Spring 19  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1A, 2G, 3S]  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn
1            80  ABC Board Spring 18  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1D, 5F, 2B]  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn
```

Comment: I had yet to come across `json_normalize` before, a bit of a hidden gem!! Thanks

Comment: `FutureWarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead` - therefore I updated to `pd.json_normalize`

Comment: thats what I have listed here

Comment: Apologizes, I had overlooked that part somehow

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten "faculty" before passing to the DataFrame constructor

For example:

```
for d in data_:
    faculty = d.pop("faculty")
    d["faculty_id"] = faculty["id"]
    d["faculty_leader"] = faculty["leader"]
```

then pass data_ to the DataFrame constructor

Comment: Thanks. However, where alternatives are available I try not to add further `loops`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DataFrame constructor on "faculty" column and `join` the resulting DataFrame back to `df` (with `add_prefix`, you could add "faculty"):

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['faculty'].tolist()).add_prefix('faculty_')).drop(columns='faculty')
```

Output:

```
   subject_code               module  \
0            90  ABC Board Spring 19   
1            80  ABC Board Spring 18   

                                               notes        topics  \
0  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1A, 2G, 3S]   
1  refer to guidance: https://nothing.com/general...  [1D, 5F, 2B]   

        start         end faculty_id faculty_leader  
0  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn  
1  1643847382  1644279382    nothing     Steve Finn
```